# NodeJS express make get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a possibility to use express as a client-module, to make http-requests to another server?

At the moment I make requests this way:

```
var req = http.get({host, path}, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        ....
    }
}
```

This is too bulky. Express as server-module is very comfortable to use. I guess there's a simple way to make a get-request by using express. I don't like the express api, and I didn't find anything there.

Comment: Express is a HTTP *server* framework, not a client.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want simple requests, don't use the *express* module, but for example [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) :

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree not to use express.

Comment: Well, you may use `express`, for answering requests, **and** `request` when you want to issue requests.

Comment: I am trying to make `https` request but it says 'socket hang up, ECONRESET' ?? Could due be the network proxy?

Comment: This answer, states to _not_ use ExpressJS when making an HTTP call to another server in NodeJS.  Does this mean ExpressJS _doesn't have the capability_ to make outbound HTTP requests?  Or is this answer suggesting using a 3rd party library for simplicity sake?

Comment: @MichaelR express is a framework making it easier to handle incoming requests. As already said, it's a *server* framework.

Comment: request is deprecated

Comment: @Rifton007 I didn't look at node recently but the whole question and answer are probably obsolete, dating from 2014. One or two years ago it seemed that the standard http(s) modules of node were good enough.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to use [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) is a bit dated, [seeing as it has been deprecated since 2019](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142).

Using Node's built-in `https.request()` method ([node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback)) does feel a bit "bulky" (IMO), but you can easily simplify it for your needs. If your use case is as you describe, then all you need is:

```js
function httpGet(host, path, chunkFunction) {
    http.get({ host, path }, (res) => res.on('data', chunkFunction));
}
```

Then implement it everywhere like:

```js
const handleChunk = (chunk) => { /* ... */ };
const req = httpGet(host, path, handleChunk);
```